# What is syntax for single quote inclusion when defining curl --noproxy in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to include --noproxy '*' with curl in a CURL definition in a bash script, i.e.

```
CURL='curl --noproxy \'*' --fail --max-time 10 --silent --output /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}\\n''
```

But this does not correctly process '*'.

echo $CURL

```
curl --noproxy \* --fail --max-time 10 --silent --output /dev/null --write-out %{http_code}\n
```

Can anyone advise as to the correct syntax for inclusion of the single quotes with *, which noproxy requires?

Comment: Why don't you simply write `--noproxy '*'`?

Comment: It does not include * when "CURL" is executed.  I am not running curl command but defining CURL=xxxx.

Comment: As an aside, you can't include single-quotes in a single-quoted string. You would need to use double quotes or `$'...'` instead. `CURL="curl --noproxy '*' ..."` or `CURL=$'curl --noproxy \'*\' ...'`.

Comment: I missed that you want to assign avariable to the whole `curl` command string. This is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to store the command somewhere, before executing it, don' use a scalar, but an array:

```
CURL=(curl --noproxy '*' --fail --max-time 10 --silent --output /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}\\n')
```

and execute it with

```
"${CURL[@]}"
```

This not only makes quoting easier, but also works if one of the arguments contains a space.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to escape *both* `'`s, but `curl` doesn't need the quotes. The quotes are simply to prevent the shell from expanding `*` before `curl` sees it. `'*'` and `\*` are equivalent.

Don't define a parameter to execute as a command; define a *function*.

```
CURL () {
  curl --noproxy '*' --fail --max-time 10 --silent --output /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}\n' "$@"
}
```

Comment: It does not behave that way when defined as CURL='............'

Comment: Behave in what way? An unquoted parameter expansion is subject to additional processing than simply typing the same text as a command. Defining `CURL` then trying to execute the command with `$CURL` is *not* the correct thing to do. Use a function instead: `CURL () { curl --noproxy '*' --fail ... ; }`.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more detail on why a function is preferred over a variable.

Comment: Can it then be used with additional arguments, i.e. CURL --insecure xxxx?

Comment: If you define the function correctly, yes. `CURL () { curl ... "$@"; }`

Comment: You need a space between `{` and `c`; braces aren't special characters, just reserved words.

Comment: It generally works but for when passed where it fails with exec: \"CURL\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: Yes, because `exec` expects an executable binary, not a shell construct.

Comment: Which is probably why it was written as it was initially.

Comment: That didn't make it correct; unquoted parameter expansions are subject to unintended word-splitting and glob expansion. If you need to use exec, it needs to be *inside* the function.